# Printing Individual Characters of Strings Python

Tags: python

My code reads

```
import time
a = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
b = len(a)
#print 1st letter of string
time.sleep(2)
#print 2nd letter of string
#continue doing that until the last character in the string
```

What would I need to do to make my code do that in Python 2.7?
Prods in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the string itself:

```
import time
a = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
for char in a:      #iterate over string one character at a time
   print char
   time.sleep(2)    # sleep after printing each character
```

Example:

```
>>> for x in "foobar":
...     print x
...     
f
o
o
b
a
r
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: t = 'input string'

In [2]: for c in t:
   ...:     print c
   ...:     
i
n
p
u
t

s
t
r
i
n
g
```